# Delete, Add more session value to repeater

Tags: asp.net

I've got this problems n till now i could not find the answer.

I create an custom cart application, and the problem occur when I'm trying to solve the final page. This cart model like a wizard, it means there are pages to be passed before getting to the last (Cart) page.

The problem here is, every value which is checked/choose in the beginning pages are saved in Session (Session["CurrentCartItem"]). And in the final cart page, the collected value in the "CurrentCartItem" Session is inserted to the "repeater".

Now the question is,

- how can I add more values in the repeater (which is returning again to the beginning pages) without the value which showed in the repeater is gone?
- And how can I delete one of the values from the repeater ?

FYI, I'm saved all the value using the Session, not database.

Please can anyone can help me to solve this problems. Maybe for other this is an easy question, but for me it's unanswered problems... :-)

Thanks in advance before...

Answer (score 0):

You should store a list of items in the session so that you can easily modify it. A simple code snippets will be

```
// class for representing item within cart
public class ShoppingCartItem { ... }

// helper method to get shopping cart from session
public static List<ShoppingCartItem> GetShoppingCart()
{
  var cart = HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart"] as List<ShoppingCartItem>;
  if (null == cart)
  {
    cart = new List<ShoppingCartItem>();
    HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart"] = cart;
  }
  return cart
}


// Add to cart
var item = new ShoppingCartItem();
// initialize item
var cart = GetShoppingCart();
cart.Add(item);
// Add to cart snippet
```

Bind the shopping cart (list) to repeater to show items within it.

```
// remove via index (say 4th item)
var cart = GetShoppingCart();
cart.RemoveAt(3);

// remove via some item property (say product code 'XYZ')
cart.RemoveAt(cart.FindIndex(c => c.ProductCode == "XYZ"));
```